# Get ListBox object from a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I am working on a `DependencyProperty` callback (`PropertyChangedCallback`) where the `sender` is a `ListBoxItem` object. I need in the code to access the `ListBox` that is containing the `ListBoxItem`.

Is it possible ?

I have tried `listBoxItem.Parent` but it is `null`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/636456/1506454

Comment: @ASh : thanks for the link, the answer is in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = sender as ListBoxItem;
    ListBox lb = FindParent<ListBox>(lbi);
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null) return null;
    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

`FindParent<ListBox>` should find the parent `ListBox` item in the visual tree.

Answer (score 6):

And the answer is:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(listBoxItem);
```

---

To clarify:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visualObject);
```

Gives you the direct parent of the given visual object.

It means that if you want the `ListBox` of the given `ListBoxItem`, since the direct parent of  `ListboxItem` is the Panel element specified by the `ItemsPanel` property, you will  have to repeat it 'till you get the `ListBox`.